# how to replace one of record with same record jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

This is part of jquery.

```
htmlAppend = jQuery("<table data-type='TempItem'></table>")
  .html(htmlTempItem)
  .find('td[data-column="No"]')
  .html(NumRow)
  .parents("table[data-type=TempItem] tbody")
  .html(); 

htmlAppend = jQuery("<table data-type='TempItem'></table>")
      .html(htmlAppend)
      .find('td[data-column="ExpressCondi"]')
      .html(item.ExpressCondi)
      .parents("table[data-type=TempItem] tbody")
      .html();
```

This is HTML Part.

```
<th><span><label>No.</label></span></th>
<th><span><label>Express Condi</label></span></th>
```

Hi guys,

1. I have 2 record in under one user.
2. 1 is APARTMENT 2 is BUNGALOW have two row. suppose have 1 row only.
3. How I can show them in one record only. which means 1  APARTMENT / BUNGALOW.

This is the example: https://gyazo.com/273e393d42a37add97cc3216cf9e0925

Thank you.

Comment: you mean call this to array then using concate back to table am I right?

Comment: yes, you can do like.